# Dirichlet's prime number theorem proof for a specific case

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Assume that for some $a$ we know that Dirichlet's prime number theorem holds. I want to prove that it holds for every $a'$ s.t $a'$ is a divisor of $a$.

We let $b\in\mathbb{N}$, and look at the sequence $a'n+b$. If $b,a$ are co-prime then it's easy. However, if $b, a$ are not co-prime, then it becomes a lot harder.
I wrote $a=a'm$ for some $m$ and tried splitting $a'n+b$ into subsequences in the following way:

$C_{mk}=a'(mk)+b=ak+b$

$C_{mk+1}=a'(mk+1)+b=ak+a'+b$
.
.
.

$C_{mk+m-1}=a'(mk+m-1)+b=ak+(m-1)a'+b$.

So basically we've taken the natural numbers and split our sequence into subsequences with respect to $n\mod m$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Now each of the subsequences is in the form of $ak+c$ for some $c$, so it suffices to prove that one of the $c's$ and a are co-primes, but I wasn't able to do it (by assuming by contradiction I couldn't get the contradiction).

Any hint would help.

Comment: So, let's say, there are infinitely many primes in $4n+1$, like $5,13,17,\ldots$. of course, then there also infinitely many primes of the form $2n+1$, for a divisor $2$ of $4$. What happens for $4n+3$ and divisors of $4$? Can you generalize?

Comment: @DietrichBurde The thing is, what happens if b=3, a=6 and a'=2?
6n+3 doesn't necessarily have infinitely many primes, but I want to prove that 2n+3 does. This is the other case (harder one) I talked about.

Comment: @GalBenAyun  In that example, it is certainly true that $6n+3$ has only finitely many primes, but $6n+5$ has infinitely many, from which it follows that $2n+5$ has infinitely many, and that is all you need.

Comment: You want to show that if $(x,y) = 1$, then there is a $y'$ with $y' \equiv y \pmod{x}$ and $(y',z) = 1$ (for an arbitrary $z > 0$; here you're looking at the situation where $x$ is a divisor of $z$, but since that doesn't help proving the result, it's best to ignore it).

Comment: @DanielFischer Why is this what I'm trying to prove? I take a $b$ s.t $b$ and $a'$ are co-prime and want to show that it has infinitely many primes, given that the dirichlet theorem is true for $a$.

Comment: $a'$ plays the rôle of $x$, $b$ that of $y$, and $a$ that of $z$. So if you have $y'$ such that $y' \equiv b \pmod{a'}$ and $(y',a) = 1$, then you know that the progression $an + y'$ contains infinitely many primes. But since $y' \equiv b \pmod{a'}$ that progression is contained in the progression $a'm + b$.

Comment: @DanielFischer can you give me a hint on how to approach it?

Comment: $y'$ has the form $mx + y$ for some $m$. We want to show that $m$ can be chosen in such a way that no prime $p$ dividing $z$ also divides $y' = mx + y$. A prime dividing $z$ either divides $y$ or it doesn't.

Comment: @DanielFischer this brings me to the exact same problem that I wrote in the thread, as I don't know how to choose such m.

Comment: Generally you do *not* choose $m$ such that $a = ma'$. For how to choose $m$, the last sentence of my previous comment gives a hint.